# Выставление задержки исполнения при использовании OnClick()

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня имеется определенный скрипт с методом, который вызывается на функцию OnClick()

```
public class SceneLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    static int currentScene = 0;
    public static bool isFinished = false;
    public GameObject LevelMenu;
    public GameObject MainMenu;
    private void Start()
    {
        MainMenu.SetActive(true);
        LevelMenu.SetActive(false);
        
    }
    public IEnumerator Delay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    }
    public static void ScenesManager()
    {
        if (isFinished == true)
        {
            currentScene++;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(currentScene);
            isFinished = false;
        }
    }
    public void InputSceneLoader()
    {
        MainMenu.SetActive(false);
        StartCoroutine(Delay());
        LevelMenu.SetActive(true);

    }
```

Необходимо сделать задержку исполнения  функций, переключающих объекты. Я пробовал **yield return** и **Invoke**, ничего не помогло

Comment: `void` -> `async void`, ну и в нужном месте задержку `await Task.Delay(1000);`. Правда не знаю, как это отработает в Unity...

Comment: `yield return` и `Invoke` в общем случае, звучит это правильно решение для реализации задержки  вызова функции. Покажите код, как вы пробовали их использовать, чтобы можно было о чем-то говорить дальше.

Comment: @RT29a в посте теперь весь код из того скрипта

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто перенесите `LevelMenu.SetActive(true);` в метод `Delay()`, сразу после `yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);`.